# Is it possible to use a field set with a custom controller?

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller, fieldsets, extension

I'm been searching the forum, but haven't found a clear answer.  Is it possible to reference a field set with only a custom controller?  I could possibly use a standard controller and an extension, but I'd like to have the link to the v/f page off of a related object and am having issues with the id that is being passed.

Comment: What about [Working with Field Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) is not clear to you?

Comment: I understand that with a standard controller you can use value="{!$ObjectType.sObject.FieldSets.FieldSetName}" var="set"> <apex:inputField value="{!sObject[set]}"/></apex:repeat>  Can you also do this with a custom controller?

Comment: Yes, you just need to set up the bindings. Do you have some code you can [edit] into your post? It might make it easier for us to help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is completely possible:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.mySpecialFields}" var="field">
        <apex:outputText value="{!field}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

You can also remove the standardController and use your custom controller

```
<apex:page Controller="myCustomController">
```

You just need to wire it up then using your controller to get the value of the fields from a map

Additional information:

http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/visualforce/using-fieldset-with-visualforce-and-apex/

This leads to my next comment, you should be able to use the standardController and extension as well without issue (Id issue mentioned in your question). So if you need to do that, post up another question and we can help you through that as well